# short exact sequence of algebras over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

Let $A,B,C$ be algebras over a field $F$ ($F=\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/p$, $p$ prime). The height of $A$ is defined to be 
$$
\mathrm{height}(A)=\sup_{a\in A}\inf\{n(a)\in \mathbb{N}\mid a^{n(a)+1}=0 \}. 
$$ 
Let $1$ be the multiplicative unit. Suppose there is an exact sequence of algebra homomorphisms preserving unit
$$
1\to A\to B\to C\to 1. 
$$
(all the algebras are cohomology rings $H^*(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)$ and homomorphisms are induced by continuous maps between manifolds. I find  the short exact sequence on Mapping class groups and function spaces, C.F. Bodigheimer, F.R. Cohen, M.D. Peim, Contemporary Mathematics, Vol. 271, 2001, page 29, Corollary 7.4.)

**Question 1:** When the sequence splits, I want to express $B$ in terms of $A,C$. Can we obtain
$$
B=A\oplus C?
$$
Is there any difference if I change the $1$'s in the above exact sequence to $0$?

**Question 2:** Can we obtain $$
\mathrm{height}(B)=\max\{\mathrm{height}(A),\mathrm{height}(C)\}
$$
or 
$$
\mathrm{height}(B)= \mathrm{height}(A)+\mathrm{height}(C)?
$$
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "there is an exact sequence $1\to A\to B\to C \to 1$"?

Comment: sorry I typed wrongly. I have modified.

Comment: Your rings do not have a unit and your morphisms don't preserve them if they do, I guess?

Comment: all the algebras are cohomology rings $H^*(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)$ and homomorphisms are induced by continuous maps between manifolds.

Comment: What does it mean for a sequence of maps of unital algebras to be exact?  The composition cannot possibly be zero (unless $A$ or $C$ is), since it must preserve the unit.

Comment: The morphisms induced by continuous maps respect identities, so you cannot have such an exact sequence.

Comment: I am very confused. I find  the short exact sequence on Mapping class groups and function spaces, C.F. Bodigheimer, F.R. Cohen, M.D. Peim, Contemporary Mathematics, Vol. 271, 2001, page 29, Corollary 7.4.